# Python import module through CLI argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I want to import a python script/module into my script based on CLI arguments. I want something like this:

```
import os
import sys
from sys.argv[1] import ClassName
# Rest of the function using the class ClassName
```

And then I want to call whatever module (a machine learning model in my case) I want from the CLI as:

```
python3 script.py model_1
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamic import module like:

```
ClassName=__import__(sys.argv[1])
ClassName.do_something()
```

or

```
import importlib
ClassName=importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1])
ClassName.do_something()
```

They are equal to `import <The Module> as ClassName`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It though does not tell me how to import a specific class, like: import arange from numpy

Comment: @MNK :Same thing:`arange=importlib.import_module("numpy").arange`.if it's a module ,you can also write like `path=importlib.import_module('os.path')`